Back button functionality for a rails app that uses turbo streams
I have a rails app that uses turbo streams, I don't use Turbo Drive because I had some issues with that in the past.
I know want to make a GET request to update some turbo streams on the DOM, and after that I want the user to be able to click on the back button and go to the previous state before the turbo-stream loading.
Is it possible to do this without Turbo Drive?

Have you seen these issues: https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/1241 or https://github.com/hotwired/turbo/issues/1300

I don't think this is a built in feature but you could use the History API together with Turbo's events to implement it.
